# simplify $n^{\log _{3}(2)}$

Tags: logarithms

Is there a way to simplify $n^{\log _{3}(2)}$ to have a result in the form of $xn$ ?

Comment: why would there be? The expression you've given is clearly not linear.

Comment: $n^{\log _{3}{2}-1}\cdot n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may solve for $x$ to obtain

$$x = n^{\log_3\frac23}
$$

but this is not a simplification

Answer (score 0):

No. $\log_3(2)$ is a constant roughly equal to $0.6309$, and the expression $n^{0.6309...}$ is not linear in $n$.